# Length of select and div elements

Tags: javascript

Why is the `<select>` and `<div>` element's `.length` different?

```html
<select id="select"></select>
<div id="myDiv">My div!
    <div></div>
</div>
```

```javascript
var select = document.getElementById('select');
var myDiv =  document.getElementById('myDiv');

console.log(select.length); // 0
console.log(myDiv.length);  // undefined
```

And why does a `select` with options has `length > 0`, if it has options inside; but the same doesn't applies to a `div` element?

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8xvN/)

Comment: What would you expect `div.length` to return?  What if it contained 5 nested divs which each had 5 nested divs?

Comment: @KevinBowersox, what surprises me is why a empty `<select>` has length...

Comment: The `length` property is [specific to `<select>`s/`HTMLSelectElement`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Properties).

Comment: The real answer to your question is because the specifications say so.

Comment: @KevinBowersox, ok. I accept that, kind of *it's how its defined to be from the beggining of times*. Do you care to post a answer?

Comment: @Rikard Johathon has it best with his link to MDN.  He should get the credit.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, thank you for the info. I will accept an answer from you if you care to post it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's [checkout the docs for `Element.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.length)

> `length` returns the number of items in a NodeList.

And:

> Despite the location of this page in the reference, length is not a property of Element, but rather of a NodeList. NodeList objects are returned from a number of DOM methods, such as document.getElementsByTagName.

So `document.getElementById` return a node, and *not* a `NodeList`.  So the `length` property on a single node is `undefined`.

---

You probably want to measure the length of the list of children instead.

```
console.log(select.children.length);
```

---

Lastly, [according to the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) `HTMLSelectElement` implements it's version of `length`, which MDN defines as:

> The number of  elements in this select element.

Most elements of other types do *not* have this property.  This is a property of `HTMLSelectElement` only.

Comment: Alex, thank you for the input! What does `document.getElementById('select')` return: a `node` or a `NodeList`? Because it has a length, defined, to `0`

Comment: @Rikard, it's an element, but also implemeting the `HTMLSelectElement` interface.

Comment: @Rikard I've updated my answer with a better explanation of that as well.  Short answer, read the docs :)

Answer (score 0):

As it [stands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById), `getElementById()` returns element.

Not all elements have concept of length  (define such property).